# Dropzone Js not uploading my files [Code Igniter]

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, dropzone.js

I was trying to upload files with using dropzone js, howewer it doesn't work I have the "upload complete animation with the progress bar" but there is not files uploaded in my uploads folder.

View :

```
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
        </form>
        <button type="button" id="submit_dropzone_form">UPLOAD</button>
    </div>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script>
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads:10,
    url: "<?php echo site_url("images/upload") ?>",
    successmultiple:function(data,response){
        $("#uploaded_files").val(response);
    },
    init: function() {
        //Submitting the form on button click
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit_dropzone_form");
            myDropzone = this; // closure
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
        });
    }
};
    </script>
</body>
```

Controller :

```
public function upload()
{
    if ( ! empty($_FILES)) 
    {
        $config["upload_path"]   = $this->upload_path;
        $config["allowed_types"] = "application/pdf";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
            echo "failed to upload file(s)";
        }
    }
}
```

where $upload_path = "./uploads"

As you can see I have a folder in my CI root project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my issue I think that the allowed types was wrong or the upload path wasn't the good one.

With this method in my controller, it work.

```
public function upload()
{
    if ( ! empty($_FILES)) 
    {
        $config["upload_path"]   = $this->upload_path;
        $config["allowed_types"] = "pdf";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
            echo "failed to upload file(s)";
        }
    }
}
```